# How to "mark" a track/ road?

Tags: unity, racing

I'm developing a simple racing game, using Unity. 
I've created a road simply applying a texture (asphalt) to a terrain . 
Is it possible (and how to do) to mark that roard with an invisible marker to identifiy that as a road (so i can make appears bonus, or others similar things) ?
Which is the approach used in a racing game to accomplish that task ? 
Please, don't tell me "buy a Roads assets" because i want to understand the basics, the main concept.

Thanks

Comment: you can add a Tag with the name Road to the terrain object and use that to identify it. I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: mmmm.. no, because : 1) i'm using a texture to 'draw' the road (is it the best way?)  2) i need to mark the terrain to make appears bonus random on roads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you want to have "Zones" in unity, you use game objects with Colliders with `isTrigger` activated.

There are two strategies you can use here. Either you surround the track with colliders to detect when the vehicle leaves the road ([`OnTriggerEnter`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html)) or you place colliders on the road and detect if the vehicle is still on the road ([`OnTriggerStay`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html)).

When you use the latter method, keep in mind that when you create your road from multiple colliders then it is possible that a vehicle triggers multiple `OnTriggerStay` events in the same frame. To handle this problem I would recommend you to have the `OnTriggerStay` method of the road colliders set a flag on the vehicle which is then retrieved in the update-method of the car.

```
public class RoadMarker : MonoBehavior
{
      void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) {
          Vehicle vehicle = other.GetComponent<Vehicle>();
          if (vehicle != null) {
               vehicle.isOnRoad = true;
          }
      }
}

public class Vehicle : MonoBehavior
{
      public bool isOnRoad;

      void Update() {
          if (isOnRoad) {
              // do what you want to do when vehicle is on the road
          } else {
              // do what you want to do when vehicle is not on the road
          }              
          isOnRoad = false; // to be changed by RoadMarker... or not
      }
}
```

Regarding placing object on the road: You could make each RoadMarker responsible for handling object spawns within its collider.